# Need help organizing and summarizing column data into R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

sorry if this has is a easy question but I have a problem

I have a .csv file imported into RStudio. Picture linked below is an example of how it looks like. I want to create individual data frames for each type (BMW, Mercedes, Honda) and then create summary statistics for each subsetted data frame.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoIkP.png)

I am pretty lost that I cant even really figure out a correct title to this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is better practice to limit your question to only 1 question. Got multiple questions; ask more separate questions . Also, adding some sampole data (use `dput()` ) increases your chances on a good answer.

Comment: I can't do much without some example data. The best practice is to put input and desired output with short explanation.

Comment: Ok I cleaned up my question and added an visual example of what my data looks like currently

Comment: I think base R should do the trick in order to subset data, ex: `merc <- df[df$Type == 'Mercedes',]`. Secondly I don't know what statistics and summary are you looking for but old good `table(merc)` gives you some desired result

Comment: Thanks so much. I honestly cant believe it what that simple. Really had a blanked out mind the past hour trying to google this and figure it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

creating single `data.frame`s for each type can be done with the `split` function, you can then calculate summary statistics for each data.frame by using `lapply` on the list of data frames.

```
split_dfs <- split(your_data, your_data$type)
summary_stats <- lapply(split_dfs, function(x){
  data.frame(
    mean_price = mean(x$price)
  )
})
```

A more modern version would be, not to create single data.frames but to use a grouped data.frame. Use `group_by` and `summarise` from the `dplyr` package.

```
require(tidyverse)

your_data %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_price = mean(price)
  )
```

Another library, that makes the computation easier and most of all faster for large datasets with many groups is the `data.table` library, the computation would look something like this.

```
require(data.table)

your_dt <- as.data.table(your_data)
summary_stats <- your_dt[, .(mean_price=mean(price)), by="type"]
```